# Python throw error byte like object required not list

Tags: python-3.x, list, sockets, memoryview

I am trying to connect the socket via the following code

```
    try:
        # create an INET, STREAMing socket
        self.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        # now connect to the web server on port 80 - the normal http port
        self.client.connect((host, port))
        user = ['User.loginByToken', access_token]
        self.client.sendall(user)
        # self.client._locust_environment = self.environment
    except Exception as e:
        color_print("\n[!] Check Server Address or Port", color="red", underline=True)
```

it throws an error `memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'list'`. what can I do to solve it?

Comment: That's not the exception you're getting, but in any event you can only send and receive bytes over the socket, so you have to encode your data into a bytes-like object. Encoding a `str` is easy, e.g. `User.loginByToken'.encode('utf-8')` will give you a `bytes` object. I have no idea what `access_token` is so you will have to figure out how to encode that. The best solution is probably to use a higher-level protocol but without more details I couldn't suggest anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert user var to bytes in order to send thru a socket:
You can try this:

```
import json

user = json.dumps({'User.loginByToken': access_token})
user = user.encode("utf-8")
```